# Corollary 5.4. in Brezis Book; $y=P_Wx\iff y\in W \ \text{and} \ \langle x-y, \omega \rangle =0.$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, hilbert-spaces

I am reading the proof of **corollary 5.4.** in Brezis book "FA, Sobolev Sp. and PDEs", I would like some clarifications.

The statement is the following

> Suppose $W$ is a closed linear subspace of $H.$ For $x\in H,$ $y=P_Wx$ is characterized by the property that for all $\omega \in W$
>   $$ y\in W \ \text{and} \ \langle x-y, \omega \rangle =0.$$

Brezis' **proof** proceeds like this:

Indeed, if $y=P_Wx$ we have already seen that for all $\omega \in W$
$$\langle x-y,\omega-y \rangle \leq 0,$$
whence for all $t\in \mathbb{R},\omega \in W$
$$\langle x-y,t\omega-y \rangle \leq 0$$

from which we obtain the desired equality $$ y\in W \ \text{and} \ \langle x-y, \omega \rangle =0.$$

**(only) question (remaining)**

> Why this passage? i.e. how does he pass from the inequality for all $t$ to the above equality?

On the other hand, if the equality above holds, we obtain in particular $$\langle x-y,\omega-y \rangle = 0$$ for all $\omega \in W.$

and thus $$y=P_Wx.$$

Comment: For $1$, note that  $W $ is a subspace and hence  $tw\in W $ for all $t\in \mathbb R $ and $w\in W $. For  $3$, expand and use the hypothesis. I don't know about  $2$.

Comment: can you say something more about 3 ? thanks

Comment: @ThomasShelby For 3:  $\langle x-y,\omega-y \rangle = \langle x-y,\omega \rangle- \langle x-y,y \rangle= 0-0=0$ because $y \in W$ OK?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\langle x-y,tw-y \rangle \leq 0$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$ and $w\in W$. We already have $y\in W$(see Theorem $5.2$ of the same textbook). In particular, for $t=2$ and $w=y$, we get $$\langle x-y,y \rangle \leq 0.$$
Now, rearranging the original inequality, we see that $$t\langle x-y,w \rangle \leq \langle x-y,y \rangle\leq0 $$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$ and $w\in W$. In particular, take $t=\langle x-y,w\rangle\in\mathbb R$(Brezis defines the inner product from $H\times H$ to $\mathbb R$). Then, $\langle x-y,w \rangle^2\leq 0$, from which the conclusion follows.